# python- modulo operator understanding

Tags: python, indexing, nlp

I bumped into some code which uses the modulo operator in a way that I haven't seen before. The line in question is `data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)`.

I have no idea what this code is trying to do when it updates `data_index`:

```
def generate_batch(batch_size, num_skips, skip_window):
    global data_index
    assert batch_size % num_skips == 0
    assert num_skips <= 2 * skip_window
    batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size), dtype=np.int32)
    labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)
    span = 2 * skip_window + 1 # [ skip_window target skip_window ]
    buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=span)
    for _ in range(span):
        buffer.append(data[data_index])

        # What is this doing?
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
# ... More stuff ...
```

Comment: It is finding the remainder when you divide `data_index + 1` by the length of `data`.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your question. In the future, please provide a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code confusing you. In this case, it's just a single line. Begin questions with as little code as necessary to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator, `%`, has a well-defined behaviour. It yields the remainder after division by a number. It is used in the expression form of `a % b`, returning a value `c`

The definition creates an interesting property, used in the code provided by your question, of "wrapping" values into a well-defined range. The code in question uses this in a loop to ensure that `data_index` is wrapped within the range of `0` to `len(data) - 1`. As it goes out of bounds, it just continues appending `data[data_index]` from 0.

Here's an example of modulo's cyclic behaviour:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(str(i) + ' % 3 =', i % 3)
```

Which prints:

```
0 % 3 = 0
1 % 3 = 1
2 % 3 = 2
3 % 3 = 0
4 % 3 = 1
5 % 3 = 2
6 % 3 = 0
7 % 3 = 1
8 % 3 = 2
9 % 3 = 0
```