# What does the modulo operator do in this code?

Tags: python, data-structures, modulo

```
class MyQueue:
​
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.q = [None] * size  # list to store queue elements
        self.capacity = size  # maximum capacity of the queue
        self.front = 0  # front points to the front element in the queue
        self.rear = -1  # rear points to the last element in the queue
        self.count = 0  # current size of the queue
​
    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            print("Queue Underflow!! Terminating process.")
            exit(1)
​
        print("Removing element…", self.q[self.front])
​
        self.front = (self.front + 1) % self.capacity
        self.count = self.count - 1
​
    def append(self, value):
        if self.is_full():
            print("Queue is full! Terminating process.")
            exit(1)
​
        print("Inserting element…", value)
​
        self.rear = (self.rear + 1) % self.capacity
        self.q[self.rear] = value
        self.count = self.count + 1
​
    def peek(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            print("Queue is empty!! Terminating process.")
            exit(1)
​
        return self.q[self.front]
​
    def size(self):
        return self.count
​
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.size() == 0
​
    def is_full(self):
        return self.size() == self.capacity
​
```

So I am currently learning Python and came across this example of a Stack data structure implemented using a class and some functions.

The problem I have is that I do not understand what the modulo operator is being used for here. As far as I can tell, Modulo is used to calculate te remainder, so in this example why do we need it for a queue?

Shouldn't it just be we want to add something to the front - so we take one away from the current front counter and add it there?

Comment: It's not a stack, it's a queue.  The modulo lets you use the data structure as a circular buffer.  You push on one end and pop from the other end,  If you push when the front pointer is at the end, it will start adding at the beginning of the list.  Say your list is 100 long, and front = 99.  When we push, we set `front = (99+1) % 100`, which is 0

Comment: This is not a stack... the class name indicates that it is a queue. It appears to be a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) implementation of a queue, and hopefully that makes clear why modular arithmetic is relevant.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51679228/12299000) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's also called a deque(double ended queue) or circular queue. The terms `front` and `rear` in that code are inadequate. `head` and `tail` are more adequate. When the queue is empty, the head is equal to the tail. When you push into the queue, the tail is increased usually. When you pop from the queue, the head is increased usually. When the head or tail reaches the end of the buffer, it is rewound to the start of the buffer. When the queue is full, the tail is just behind the head usually.

In a circular queue, you don't need to shift elements while popping elements like a stack.(If you implement a naive queue with a list, `list.pop(0)` results in shifting elements and that's O(N).)

Using a modulo operator for calculating a head or tail index is a trick to rewind an index.

```
tail = (tail + 1) % N
# The above one line is equivalent to the following.
tail = tail + 1
if tail >= N:
    tail = 0
```

It's implemented as the [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) in the standard library.